# Random movement pygame

Tags: python, random, pygame, game-physics

I'm trying to make a simple life simulator, and I need the "cells" to move almost randomly (with a few rules) across the screen. But the problem is, after a while they tend to bunch up in the upper-left corner of the screen. I tried to change a lot of things, like completely skipping the rules and making them move completely randomly, but they still bunch up. Is there some obvious problem in my code? Or should I be doing the movement completely differently?

The code with irrelevant parts cut out:

```
import sys, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

WIDTH = 640 #game window width
HEIGHT = 480 #game window height
FPS = 60 #game's speeds
Pixsize = 2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) #set the game window


class cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(10, WIDTH-10) #x position
        self.y = random.randrange(10, HEIGHT-10) #y position
        self.speed = random.randrange(2,5) #cell speed
        self.move = [None, None] #realtive x and y coordinates to move to
        self.direction = None #movement direction

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (self.x,self.y,Pixsize,Pixsize),0) #draw the cell


    def wander(self):
        directions = {"S":((-1,2),(1,self.speed)),"SW":((-self.speed,-1),(1,self.speed)),"W":((-self.speed,-1),(-1,2)),"NW":((-self.speed,-1),(-self.speed,-1)),"N":((-1,2),(-self.speed,-1)),"NE":((1,self.speed),(-self.speed,-1)),"E":((1,self.speed),(-1,2)),"SE":((1,self.speed),(1,self.speed))} #((min x, max x)(min y, max y))
        directionsName = ("S","SW","W","NW","N","NE","E","SE") #possible directions
        if random.randrange(0,5) == 2: #move about once every 5 frames
            if self.direction == None: #if no direction is set, set a random one
                self.direction = random.choice(directionsName)
            else:
                a = directionsName.index(self.direction) #get the index of direction in directions list
                b = random.randrange(a-1,a+2) #set the direction to be the same, or one next to the current direction
                if b > len(directionsName)-1: #if direction index is outside the list, move back to the start
                    b = 0
                self.direction = directionsName[b]
            self.move[0] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][0][0],directions[self.direction][0][1]) #change relative x to a random number between min x and max x
            self.move[1] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][1][0],directions[self.direction][1][1]) #change relative y to a random number between min y and max y
        if self.x < 5 or self.x > WIDTH - 5 or self.y < 5 or self.y > HEIGHT - 5: #if cell is near the border of the screen, change direction
            if self.x < 5:
                self.direction = "E"
            elif self.x > WIDTH - 5:
                self.direction = "W"
            elif self.y < 5:
                self.direction = "S"
            elif self.y > HEIGHT - 5:
                self.direction = "N"
            self.move[0] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][0][0],directions[self.direction][0][1]) #change relative x to a random number between min x and max x
            self.move[1] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][1][0],directions[self.direction][1][1]) #change relative x to a random number between min x and max x
        if self.move[0] != None: #add the relative coordinates to the cells coordinates
            self.x += self.move[0]
            self.y += self.move[1]


cells = []
for i in range(200): #generate n cells
    Cell = cell()
    cells.append(Cell)


def mainloop():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type== QUIT: #if pressing the X, quit the progra
                pygame.quit() #stop pygame
                sys.exit() #stop the program
        screen.fill((0,0,0)) #clear the screen;
        for i in cells: #update all cells
            i.wander()
            i.draw()
        pygame.display.update() #update display
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS) #limit FPS

mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a suggestion on something I noticed. It might make more sense for `move` to be a 2-tuple instead instead of a list since it seems to always contain exactly 2 elements.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You mean instead of doing 
move[0] = random x
move[1] = random y
I should do 
move = (random x, random y)?
And if so, why would it be better than what I have now?

Comment: I mean, `self.move` is a list of movement directions; but there's only ever 2 entries in it. Typically if you have a container that's always is the same size, you use a tuple to prevent accidental appends that might mess with existing code. If it shouldn't be appended, it shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand why now, I'll use a tuple then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Np. You game me things to think about over lunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of random number generators tend to favour smaller numbers. You may need to offset the random values by some other tiny random number, or look into more sophisticated generators.

I looked around quickly, and I couldn't find any "truly" random generators.

Try adding a tiny number to the other random numbers and see start happens.

Just to clarify what I meant:

```
#Instead of:

self.move[0] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][0][0],directions[self.direction][0][1])
self.move[1] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][1][0],directions[self.direction][1][1])

#Try something like:

smallOffset = random.random() #Random floating-point number between 0 and 1 ("Tiny number")

self.move[0] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][0][0],directions[self.direction][0][1]) + smallOffset
self.move[1] = random.randrange(directions[self.direction][1][0],directions[self.direction][1][1]) + smallOffset
```

You may have to adjust `smallOffset` to limit how large it can get (because, it can be a value up to almost 1, which isn't really small anymore)

Comment: After a bit of testing, I realized that, indeed, the random number generator is what caused the cells to bunch up. But I can't understand, how I should "add a tiny number to other random numbers" to make it better.

Comment: Well, if it is because your generator is slightly biased toward smaller numbers, you can add a small number to try to compensate for the bias. I'll see if I can whip up an example, and update my answer.

Comment: @Uxeron I added an example. Please let me know if you still need clarification.

Comment: I tried your idea, and, with a bit of fine-tuning the offset, it now works correctly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Np. It was a shot in the dark, so I'm glad it worked. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your cells are bunching up to the top-left is because of `random.randrange()`.

The `randrange()` part handles the range, [as per the python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) `range()` function.  Looking at the `range()` function, `range( A, B )` returns a list `A` -> `B-1`:

```
>>> for i in range( 1,10 ): print( i, end = ", " )
... 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

So when your code is doing `random.randrange(directions[self.direction][0][0],directions[self.direction][0][1])`, it's excluding the last item in the range, which looks to be "SE".  Hence they're a little more likely to head in the other directions, and after thousands of iterations, that moves them to the top-left corner.