# Pygame Random Dot movement with GPU Accelaration

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, gpu

I have asked about the frames dropping in my project before, after putting it off for a month as I lost motivation I thought about it and realised I could use my GPU to handle the graphics processing. I have been looking at PyOpenGL (As recommended by my teacher, however this was when I asked about GPU rendering in general, not about 2D GPU rendering) which I am now slightly comfortable with 3D graphics rendering however, I am planning on making my game 2D not 3D and I am struggling to work out how to use 2D rendering.

All I am trying to do is generate a given amount of pixels on the screen in random locations that will move randomly, as I have said before I have achieved this in normal PyGame with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015787/random-movement-pygame) but it runs at around 20fps, with the number of cells I wish to generate, which isn't fast enough.

Should I stick with PyOpenGL (If so how would I use it) or is there another library I should be using?

Comment: You could try speeding up your python code with a compiler like pypy or cython.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you should really investigate using Open**GL** **S**hader **L**anguage (GLSL).  There's a few tutorials around: https://www.pythonstuff.org/glsl/ .

If you want to play with GLSL, that's great.  But if the reason you're investigating GLSL is to optimise your code, (A) Don't do that. and (B) looking at [your existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015787/random-movement-pygame), there are significant gains to be had from simple changes.

For starters, in the `wander()` function, you're re-defining the `directions` dictionary, for every cell, every frame:

```
def wander(self):
    directions = {"S":((-1,2),(1,self.speed)),"SW":((-self.speed,-1),(1,self.speed)),"W":((-self.speed,-1),(-1,2)),"NW":((-self.speed,-1),(-self.speed,-1)),"N":((-1,2),(-self.speed,-1)),"NE":((1,self.speed),(-self.speed,-1)),"E":((1,self.speed),(-1,2)),"SE":((1,self.speed),(1,self.speed))} #((min x, max x)(min y, max y))
    directionsName = ("S","SW","W","NW","N","NE","E","SE") #possible directions
```

These variables never change, it could easily be created in the `__init__()`, giving a nice speedup.

```
class cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(10, WIDTH-10) #x position
        self.y = random.randrange(10, HEIGHT-10) #y position
        self.speed = random.randrange(2,5) #cell speed
        self.move = [None, None] #realtive x and y coordinates to move to
        self.direction = None #movement direction
        self.directions = {"S":((-1,2),(1,self.speed)),"SW":((-self.speed,-1),(1,self.speed)),"W":((-self.speed,-1),(-1,2)),"NW":((-self.speed,-1),(-self.speed,-1)),"N":((-1,2),(-self.speed,-1)),"NE":((1,self.speed),(-self.speed,-1)),"E":((1,self.speed),(-1,2)),"SE":((1,self.speed),(1,self.speed))} #((min x, max x)(min y, max y))
        self.directionsName = ("S","SW","W","NW","N","NE","E","SE") #possible directions

     # Obviously wander() needs matching changes too.
```

Also you're using a dictionary for `self.directions`, and while this is quite fast, it's not nearly fast as using a simple numerical index into an array.  The strings "SW" etc. could be re-defined as an indexed enumerated types, so "S" is 0, "SW" is 1, etc. indexing into a fixed-size list.

With a lot of separate cells, living in a sparsely populated world, it may eventually help to partition the cellular community into a [data structure like a quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) so you can efficiently search for neighbours, based geographic co-ordinates etc.

I think it's best that your just write your cellular simulation.  Get it working properly in python.  If... If it's then *too* slow, optimise the slow bits.  But don't immediately reach for hardware acceleration right at the beginning, because bad algorithms, even on hardware, are still slow.